# Datetime to Date

Tags: dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with several columns in the date time format. I converted them to date using teh following df["Value date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Value date"]).dt.date. WHen I write it into excel the column appears as "2023-07-31". SO it is changing it into a date. However when I read this file into another dataframe for further processing and then write into Excel it reverts back to a datetime. Please can you tell me what I need to do differently to make sure that this field remains as a date and does not revert to datetime

Also when I convert to date how do I specify the format to be "31/07/2023" instead of "2023-07-31".
Many thanks

I used the formula df["Value date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Value date"]).dt.date as outlined above

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df["Value date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Value date"], format="%Y-%m-%d", dayfirst=True).dt.strftime(date_format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, there is no date type - dates/times are numbers - the number of days since 1899/12/31, with the whole number being the whole days, and the fraction bring the fraction of the day since midnight.
The number 45412.7589 can be displayed as 30/04/2024, 2024/04/30 18:12, or 18:12:49 or any other combination.

If your final result is Excel, don't do any formatting in Python because Excel will try to be clever on the import - just get the value to Excel and do the formatting there (the MS support docs are pretty clear on how to do that)

Comment: The use of numbers means that finding the difference between two points in time is trivial E.g. `=A3-A2 and then format the answer in days or hours and minutes as required.